# Running a curl or wget request over a VPN (from shell) without affecting system's main connection

Tags: shell, curl, openvpn, vpn, wget

Is there a way to run a `curl` or `wget` request over a VPN in a way that doesn't affect the rest of the system's networking?

So I don't want to activate the VPN system-wide, as that would presumably tunnel all system traffic through the VPN (which I don't want).

I have a VPN server + username + password (OpenVPN IKEv2 credentials), is there a way to do this using a shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with namespaces.

For a guide try https://schnouki.net/post/2014/openvpn-for-a-single-application-on-linux/

Comment: Namespaces aren't a systemd thing. Every distro has them regardless of what they use for init or service management.

Comment: @cryptarch thanks - I removed that part.

Comment: Thanks, I removed my -1 vote :) I reckon the answer could be improved if you gave more detailed instructions instead of only pointing to a 7yo link. If you do that and ping me, I'll probably add a +1 vote. Btw, `ip netns` is awesome. I have some scripts at https://notabug.org/cryptarch/vpnutils/